# need help in running a bat file but only after restart (log off/on not included)

Tags: windows, batch-file

i have a certain program that i want to run as windows boots up
but! i need it to be only after windows restart not log off and log on are out of the question - the system i have is running tests and and the app that i want to run is canceling those tests that`s why i need it to run only after windows restarts , so there is no chance that a tests would fail because of it
the .bat file points to the location of

tried shell:common startup but that open the .bat file even after  i log off or log on

how do i do this ? i need this to be in a script/.bat file as well

Comment: Already answered on SV? https://serverfault.com/questions/363164/how-to-kick-off-a-batch-file-on-server-restart

Comment: it didnt work out for me any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

You should add it here
`C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

But cause you mentioned after only restart then you will need to run an background script to handle that restart

Or we may..

The common command to restart windows via .bat or cmd file is `shutdown -r`

So we can create
`reboot.bat` ,`script.bat` ,`mover.bat` > for example in `'C:\test'` directory

**reboot.bat**

```
move script.bat "C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\script.bat"
shutdown -r
```

**script.bat**

```
: : stuff here..  
C:\test\mover.bat
```

**mover.bat**

```
move "C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\script.bat" script.bat
```

now that we have our scripts let's add them to our **Environment variables**

1. From the desktop, right click the Computer icon.
2. Choose Properties from the context menu.
3. Click the **Advanced system settings** link.
4. Click **Environment Variables**.
5. In the section System Variables, find the **PATH** environment variable
   and select it.
6. Click **Edit** then add `;` following by `C:\test` Click Ok, Ok etc and
   restart your cmd if opened

To answer your question just type `reboot.bat` or `reboot` in `CMD` command-line

Which when you want to run your script after restart you have to type `this` to cmd or just..make a `restart.bat` file with `this command` for just one click

> I used stack overflow for android to answer this without test cause i'm not windows but i'm just familiar with plus didn't have my PC at this moment but i hope that answer is clear and understandable

Answer (score 0):

I would say use the [Windows Task Scheduler](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-schedule-batch-file-run-automatically-windows-7)